# Rails has_many association with a class that contains an enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, rspec-rails

I have a class `Shower` like so:

```
class Shower < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :capabilities, dependent: :destroy

  //more code
end
```

and a class `Capability`:

```
class Capability < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :shower

  validates_presence_of :capability

  enum capability: [
    :mobile_supports_pusher,
    :hmi_supports_pusher
  ]
end
```

Now I'm trying to create tests that make sure a created capability is valid or invalid:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Capability do
  it "is invalid without required attributes" do
    capability = Capability.create
    expect(capability).to_not be_valid
    expect(capability.errors.keys).to eq [:capability]
  end

  it "is valid with all required attributes" do
    shower = FactoryGirl.create :shower
    capability = shower.capabilities.create(capability: :mobile_supports_pusher)
    expect(capability).to be_valid
  end
end
```

But no matter what value I put in for `capability`, it's always `nil` and I'm not sure if it's because I'm doing it wrong or this is a limitation.

For example if I do `c = Capability.create!(capability: 0)` in the console, it saves correctly.

Is it possible to have an association like this? Basically we want a `Shower` to have any number of `Capabilities` but only one of each for the enum, if that makes sense.

Comment: Can you post the output of running the tests?

Comment: I ran your code as published here and it works without error. The problem must be in something you didn't publish. OT: The naming you're working with is a little confusing, specifically: `capability.capability`. IMO, this would be better represented as a HABTM relationship where Capability is a lookup. At a minimum, I would rename the enum to something like `name`.

Comment: Ya, I think it was actually due to a database migration that went awry that was causing the tests to fail.  Does that make sense at all?